# Why is there a MySQL Syntax Error (java)?

Tags: java, mysql

Error: `[14:39:52] [Server thread/WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'integer)' at line 1`

The codeline of the error: `MySQL.update("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kititems"(kit varchar(32),item varchar(32),index integer)");`

please help me

Comment: index is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use "index" as a column name.

Comment: /you could improve  this answer by stating why not

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your comment (index is a reserved word) explains the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think "index" is a reserved word. Try another name.
Also, there is a " after kititems that should not be there.